# $classInstance->title is faster than $classInstance->getTitle() - so why do most people use the slower method?

Tags: php, performance, oop, scalability

I've recently been reading up articles on how to optimize code for scalability in PHP. Several of the articles I've read today have discouraged the use of additional methods to simply return objects from a class.

So basically, they say:

If you have a class like this:

```
class myClass
{

public $something;

public function setSomething($val)
{

$this->something=$val;

}//function end

}//class end

$myClassInstance=new myClass;
```

And you want to get the class property `$something`, you should do this:

```
//echo $something from myClass
echo $myClassInstance->something;
```

And not this:

```
//echo $something from myClass using an additional method (getSomething()) that returns the property
echo $myClassInstance->getSomething();
```

Because there is a speed difference. The discouraged method is slower (`$myClassInstance->getSomething()`) which is why it is discouraged.

But, I see so many people still using the discouraged method (tutorials, code examples, ect). I could understand if they **had** to have the property set to private for whatever reason, but this is generally not the case.

So my question is, is there a benefit or something that I am missing to using the discouraged method? If so, what?

Comment: Why? You might not want to allow assignment as in `if( $myClassInstance->something = 0 ) {`.  Oops.  **Double Oops**.  Encapsulation facilitates abstraction and validation.   A good compromise is to use the magic methods __get() and __set();

Comment: @TerryE Magic methods are even slower but are not evil tho, so if the question is why choose accessors vs properties, the using magic methods is definitely not the way to go althought it can be very practical, i use them often

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, using minimal a magic `__get()` adds about 0.2μS per property reference, and slightly more if you are doing addition functionality in the method.  The total load per URI request is _tiny_ compared to other areas which deserve optimisation focus, such as MySQL optimisation or HTTP cache and fetch optimisation.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, why use magic methods: IMO `$cxt->admin` is just simpler to code and easier on the eye than `$cxt->getAdmin()`

Comment: @TerryE Agreed on the area of optimization, but if you can, declare your accessors and use them instead of using __get() with switches and ifs and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you wanted to apply some logic to your "GetTitle" later such as filters or change some of the output by introducing special logic? You never know when these things will start popping out.

Additionnaly, people saying the function accessor style is slower are using a 1 million loops to benchmark it, but seriously, are you going to display 1 million titles on a page?

Comment: Well said about the benchmarks - that's why mankind invented pages (pagination), to not have to drag the meter-long scrolls against the asphalt. :)

Answer (score 5):

The reason for someone to use `getter` and `setter` methods is due to `encapsulation`. Directly accessing `$something` would render it both `readable` and `writeable`, however accessing it via `getSomething()` would instead just give the caller a copy (ie won't alter the original value).